# Generate trx file through code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xmlwriter, trx

I want to manually generate TRX file through for my code.

Is there any program which will be used for this purpose.
If not then how to do it?

Comment: Here is a link providing rough step-by-step instructions.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028962/how-to-programmtically-generate-a-trx-file

Answer (score 3):

This post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dhopton/archive/2008/06/12/helpful-internals-of-trx-and-vsmdi-files.aspx talks about trx and vmdi files and is a useful starting point. You can find the xsd on a computer with visual studio installed at %VSINSTALLDIR%\xml\Schemas\vstst.xsd.

If you plan to open your custom trx files in VS, not that I can think for any other good reason to create them, the errors you will get from VS for non compliant files is almost no existent. VS seems to require more than the minimum set defined in the XSD.

Good luck.

Comment: That blog post is an excellent place to start looking at the issue. Especially take care of the Guids (which are hard coded and which can be generated). Also a good way to start is a create one simple unit test with 2 cases with the other failing. This way you'll get a short example of all the elements that are required.